# android viewpager - swiping

Tags: android, android-activity, android-viewpager, swipe

I've read this blog about viewpager:

http://android-developers.blogspot.sk/2011/08/horizontal-view-swiping-with-viewpager.html

and I have a question; can I use it to swipe between unknown amount of activities? because in the example were 5 tabs and you could swipe between them, but I need something, that can swipe between activities forever. something that will have method onSwipeRight or left, incerement some integer there and show appropriate activity. and I can't do it with fragments, because it gives me some nullpointer exceptions - I think that interface that I want cant be done with fragments. Thanks

Comment: If you talk about swiping between `Activities` and not just `Views`, then you probably do want `Fragments`; you may be better off editing your question to tell us about the `NullPointerExceptions` you're getting when you try.

Comment: i do everything by the fragment guide on developer.android.com but one fragment is listfragment and the other one is just fragment and when i implement it, the pointer to fragment which should fullfill container is null, no idea why.. and theres another problem, because while one fragment active, i want there action bar, fragment and some buttons on the bottom but when will be the second fragment active, there should be buttons on top and webview under it, and i dont think that could be done within one activity

Comment: Please post the error you're getting, along with some code.  Your fragment can contain any view you choose to put in it, whether it contains buttons or a list or a webview.  Which view is shown is handled by the Fragment that's visible.  The Activity will control the action bar, but you can use a contextual action bar (http://developer.android.com/guide/topics/ui/menus.html#CAB) to change which options are displayed for which fragment.  We can help more if you show us the errors.

Comment: i am using sherlock action bar because of compatibility and layout is like: main activity has action bar at top, then comes list fragment and at the bottom are some buttons. when you click on item from list, acrticle will show - no action bar, only 2 buttons on top and webview of article. thats the point, i can put another fragment into container, in which listfragment was, but the actionbar and buttons on the bottom will remain, wont them? is a way to do it with fragments? i'll add some code tommorow, its midnight here.

Comment: `getSupportActionBar().hide()` should hide the action bar if called from within one of your fragments.  And you would use a custom layout for your `ListFragment` which contained both the list and the buttons at the bottom, while the layout for your `ArticleFragment` would contain the `WebView` and the buttons at the top.

Comment: okay, that sounds nice. I want to achieve that you can pick item from list and then you can swipe between items from list. there are many items. is that possible with viewpager?

Comment: Yes; however, you'll probably want one activity for the list, and another containing fragments (based on your list items) that you swipe between. You should post that as a separate question.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Consider using Fragments for swiping through them.

Comment: i am using sherlock action bar because of compatibility and layout is like: main activity has action bar at top, then comes list fragment and at the bottom are some buttons. when you click on item from list, acrticle will show - no action bar, only 2 buttons on top and webview of article. thats the point, i can put another fragment into container, in which listfragment was, but the actionbar and buttons on the bottom will remain, wont them? is a way to do it with fragments?

Comment: Action bar can be hidden and shown as needed by using actionBar.hide()/show().
The question can transcend more to usability matters. Would the actionBar stop to be necessary in the webView? Will it cause a weird effect to the user?

If everything fits, go for it.